# Adding information to a view not yet loaded

Tags: java, android

Currently I have a ListView which gets populated correctly. When clicking on a row, I have this call back:

```
   private void registerClickCallBack() {
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.carsListView);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewClicked, int position, long id) {
                Car clickedCar = myCars.get(position);
                String message = "Your password \""+clickedCar.getMake() + "\" has been copied to your clipboard ";
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                clipboard.setText(clickedCar.getMake().toString());
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), view_selected_item.class);

                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
                TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.asdasd); // I have made sure asdasd is really a value
                tv.setText("asd"); // tv is null

            }
        });
    }
```

The above code works if these two lines are commented out.

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.asdasd); // I have made sure asdasd is really a value
tv.setText("asd"); // tv is null
```

The intent is to have the call create a new view which startActivityForResult does. How do I set a value to the Textfields on the newly created page.

Basically, Im asking how do I pass information to view that has not been created yet. In this case view_selected_item.class

Comment: startActivityForResult is going to return an int and an intent object in onActivityResult generated by the new activity. It's not really clear what you're trying to do so that's as much as I can say.

Comment: May I suggest a resource ID other than "asdfasdf"

Comment: asdasd is the resource id @grennis. Basically, Im asking how do I pass information to view that has not been created yet. In this case view_selected_item.class

Comment: OK I updated my answer on how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass information through an Intent you use extras.

For example `intent.putExtra("key", "value")` and in your activity, use `getIntent().getStringExtra("key")`